What makes my T-SQL query non-composable and therefore non-compatible with EF Core's SqlQuery?
I'm writing some T-SQL queries that I can use with EF Core, but I'm getting an error saying that my query is not composable. I tried searching about writing composable queries but didn't find anything that made sense to me.
I'm finding myself here because I'm getting an error in my C# code that says:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'FromSql' or 'SqlQuery' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

What about my query below makes it non-composable? Is it my use of CTEs? They query has no params or anything.
WITH CollectionInformation AS (
  SELECT
    c.Id AS CollectionId,
    c.Name AS CollectionName,
    p.Name AS ProjectName,
    t.Id AS TaxonomyId,
    t.Name AS TaxonomyName,
    c.DateCreated
  FROM Collections AS c
  JOIN Projects AS p ON p.Id = c.PrimaryProjectId
  JOIN Taxonomies AS t ON t.Id = c.TaxonomyId
),
SessionCounts AS (
  SELECT
    s.CollectionId,
    COUNT(s.Id) AS SessionCount
  FROM Sessions AS s
  JOIN CollectionInformation AS c ON c.CollectionId = s.CollectionId
  GROUP BY s.CollectionId
),
BoxCount AS (
  SELECT
    c.CollectionId,
    COUNT(z.Id) AS ZipfileCount
  FROM BoxZipfiles AS z
  JOIN Sessions AS s ON s.Id = z.SessionId
  JOIN CollectionInformation AS c ON c.CollectionId = s.CollectionId
  GROUP BY c.CollectionId
)
SELECT c.*, s.SessionCount, b.ZipfileCount
FROM CollectionInformation AS c
JOIN SessionCounts AS s ON s.CollectionId = c.CollectionId
JOIN BoxCount AS b ON b.CollectionId = c.CollectionId


WITH makes this query non-composable. EF cannot put your query into subquery.

It is straightforward to change the cte to a subquery.

Not particularly straightforward as CollectionInformation is referenced twice and derived tables can't be so you'd need to repeat that whole definition. I'd be looking to simplify this not just replace CTEs with derived tables

Watch out with those inner joins, if you don't have any count it might remove the rows altogether

You can create a view with that expression and use the view with SqlQuery. If you pass such a large SQL string to SqlQuery, something's wrong. If you want to use parameters, you can use a UDF

WITH specifies a Common Table Expression, which in SQL Server is not composable inside other queries.
While you could just copy out the CollectionInformation CTE into each of its references, I think you can almost certainly write this query better anyway, by combining BoxCounts and SessionCounts into the outer query as aggregated subqueries.
SELECT
  c.Id AS CollectionId,
  c.Name AS CollectionName,
  p.Name AS ProjectName,
  t.Id AS TaxonomyId,
  t.Name AS TaxonomyName,
  c.DateCreated,
  s.SessionCount,
  s.ZipfileCount
FROM Collections AS c
JOIN Projects AS p ON p.Id = c.PrimaryProjectId
JOIN Taxonomies AS t ON t.Id = c.TaxonomyId
JOIN (  -- do you want LEFT JOIN?
    SELECT
      s.CollectionId,
      COUNT(*) AS SessionCount
      SUM(z.ZipfileCount) AS ZipfileCount
    FROM Sessions AS s
    JOIN (  -- do you want LEFT JOIN?
        SELECT
          z.SessionId,
          COUNT(*) AS ZipfileCount
        FROM BoxZipfiles AS z
        GROUP BY
          z.SessionId
    ) z ON z.SessionId = s.Id
    GROUP BY
      s.CollectionId
) s ON s.CollectionId = c.CollectionId;

Now you could probably write this as a normal EF query anyway.
var results = await db.Collections
    .Include(c => c.PrimaryProject)
    .Include(c => c.Taxonomy)
    .Select(c => new {
        Collection = c,
        Counts = c.Sessions
            .Select(s => new { s, ZipfileCount = s.BoxZipfiles.Count() })
            .GroupBy(s => 1)
            .Select(g => new {
                SessionCount = g.Count(),
                ZipfileCount = g.Sum(s => s.ZipfileCount),
            })
            .FirstOrDefault(),
    })
    .ToListAsync();

